# Array result in Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get products of selected brands `can be 1 or more (using checkbox)` in laravel but it returns result of only one of my selected brands.

`Form`

```
<form action="{{route('mysearch')}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}

<div class="filter-content">
  <div class="checkbox">
   @foreach($brands as $brand)
    <label for="brands">
     <input name="brands[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$brand->id}}">
      {{$brand->title}}
    </label>
   @endforeach
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">submit</button>
</form>
```

`function`

```
public function mysearch(Request $request) {
 $brands = Brand::OfStatus('Active')->get();
 $brand = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : [];
 $products = Product::where('brand_id', '=', $brand)->get();
 return view('front.search', compact('products', 'brands'));
}
```

If I choose brands `lenovo` and `lg` I only get result of `lenovo` brand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `whereIn`:

```
Product::whereIn('brand_id', $brand)->get();
```

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @djhru please show result of `dd($request->brands);`

Comment: it's working i'm sorry. (please wait 10 min till i'm allowed to accept your answer)